# Administrators and TestedUsers

Tags: sql, relational-database

i am building an application where users would get their english level tested with various tests.

I have administrators that can create a user and give them an english test by sending them an email with the credentials.Once they login, they will be redirected to the test.

Would it be okay to put Administrators in one table and and tested users in another table then have them login from the same page, or should i mix Adminstrators with testedusers.

I was thinking banks keep their Administrator staff and customers in separate tables even thought they log in from the same screen.

That should keep my data access logic as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `user-role` relationship in this situation. the simple one could be a 1-to-many relation (any user has only one role)

- one table for users: `user(userid, username, password, roleid)`
- one table for role: `role(roleid, rolename)`

`roleid` in `user` table is a foreign-key from `role` table.

actual data may be:

```
roleid  rolename
----------------
111111  admin
222222  simple
```

and

```
userid  username    password    roleid
--------------------------------------
111111  AAAAAAAA    ********    111111
222222  BBBBBBBB    ********    222222
333333  CCCCCCCC    ********    222222
444444  DDDDDDDD    ********    222222
555555  EEEEEEEE    ********    222222
```

then

```
select roleid
from user 
where username='AAAAAAAA' and password='*******'
```

after login based on user's role you can decide about actions he can do. you also can add a `permission` table that defines permission of any role. the you need a `role-permission` table for many-to-many relation of role and permission...

Comment: my problem is that my users are fundamentally different.Administrators only need a name and a pass while testeduser need age, gender, salary, phone and also a table to store their test scores.